# Indexing JSON arrays of integers using Mariadb?

Tags: arrays, json, mariadb, query-optimization, generated-columns

I'm storing arrays of integers as json in a mariadb (10.3.23) table :

```
SELECT 
    tag_list 

FROM 
    dw.final_document 

LIMIT 1 ;
```

Result :

```
[903, 1258, 1261, 393]
```

To retrieve entries matching a specific id, this works :

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
    count(*) 
     
FROM 
    dw.final_document 

where 
    JSON_CONTAINS(tag_list, 684 ) ;
```

Result :

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     9696 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2.084 sec)
```

However the performance is not good without an index (2 sec in a 1M rows table)

The possibility to index a specific field of the json is well documented ([percona post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/07/json-document-fast-lookup-with-mysql-5-7/)).

You can add an index on a generated column like this :

```
ALTER TABLE test_features 
ADD COLUMN street VARCHAR(30) 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`feature`,'$.properties.STREET'))) VIRTUAL;
```

**Is there a similar way to index arrays of integers ?**